# Designing Ichat balloon interface

Tags: iphone

I am trying for chat balloon kind of interface on iphone, I am able to draw a rounded rect thing and also am able to draw the gradients. But not getting how to achieve gradient drawing in rounded rect.I'll be thankful for any help..

Comment: Welcome to StackOverflow.  We're happy to help, but we need you to make an attempt first.  What have you tried?

Comment: first off thanks. I was trying.. I am able to draw a rounded rect thing and also am able to draw the gradients. But not getting how to achieve gradient drawing in rounded rect.

Comment: Ok, that's a much better and more specific question.  Edit your post to ask that.  Explain in detail what you've done, what you're trying to do, and why it isn't working.

Comment: A quick warning: another developer had their app rejected because their chat balloons were too similar to the ones in the Messages app. It sounds to me like you could be describing the same thing: http://www.iphonesavior.com/2009/09/developer-battles-apple-over-shiny-chat-bubbles.html

Answer (score 3):

First you need to work out the size of the text to fit in the area

```
CGSize size = [string sizeWithFont:[UIFont systemFontOfSize:14]
                     constrainedToSize:CGSizeMake(300, 900)
                         lineBreakMode:UILineBreakModeWordWrap];
```

Draw the text in that size

```
- (void)drawRect:(CGRect)rect {

    [self.text drawInRect:rect withFont:self.font lineBreakMode:UILineBreakModeWordWrap|UILineBreakModeTailTruncation alignment:UITextAlignmentLeft];

}
```

I used a stretchable UIImage to fit behind the text

```
UIImage *myImage = [[UIImage imageNamed:@"balloon.png"]  stretchableImageWithLeftCapWidth:23 topCapHeight:13];
```

Popped it in a UIImageView and set the frame to the be the same size as the text plus a bit of padding.

Hope this helps